# Are there real differences between NUnit and Microsoft's Unit Testing Framework (VS 2008)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, testing, nunit

With the framework that Visual Studio 2008 has, am I missing anything great by NOT using an external tool like NUnit?  From what I can tell it seems like using NUnit would be more of a hassle with manually creating test classes and methods versus the right clicking native to the IDE.  That being said, am I missing features that NUnit provides that VS doesn't contain?  Having a simple GUI for my QA people to access is fine and all, but using nAnt and the build dependencies on unit tests passing, am I missing cool features?

Comment: The answers to this question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92869/nunit-vs-visual-studio-2008s-test-projects-for-unit-testing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Roy Osherove just wrote a recent [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2010/03/05/nunit-vs-mstest-nunit-wins-for-unit-testing.aspx) summarizing the differences between NUnit and MSTest. I think it answers your question.

He concludes that NUnit wins for Unit Testing, but MsTest has much better abilities for integration based testing and team testing with Team System.

Comment: @Paddyslacker: Nowhere in Roy's blog post does he make any statements to the fact that "NUnit is far superior for true unit testing".

Comment: Fixed the conclusion to match the title of the blog post. Thanks for keeping me honest, Scott!

Comment: They're really pretty much the same IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out Roy's post and also found this link back to here.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487773/is-there-anything-i-can-do-in-nunit-that-i-cant-do-in-mstest/

Good stuff, now I just need to test drive NUnit in a real app first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I have used both NUnit and MSTest. Yes, there are differences. NUnit is an older, more established unit testing framework designed to do exactly one thing - unit testing. MSTest is newer so it does not have the same level of maturity in its API. For example, NUnit offers more Assert methods than MSTest. (See [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015064737/http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/01/31/migrating-from-nunit-to-mstest.aspx) for more information. To add some of the missing Assert methods, see [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160708001201/http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/01/31/adding-custom-assertions-to-mstest.aspx)).

I have not really found performance to be an issue with either framework.

Some of the bigger differences are:

- MSTest requires a Visual Studio instance on the build server in order to run. It does not contain a standalone test runner like NUnit.
- MSTest provides test results **and** code coverage results directly within Visual Studio. NUnit provides test results in its own UI and requires additional tools to perform code coverage analysis.

Answer (score 2):

See [MSBuild, NAnt, NUnit, MSTest, and frustration](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2006/12/08/msbuild-nant-nunit-mstest-and-frustration.aspx). If you're not using TFS as your CI/build server, you may want to seriously consider NUnit or one of the other open source projects.

Answer (score 1):

I use MSTest at work because I have to, and to be honest, I find it slow and irritating. If I had my choice, it would be xunit.net (basically like nunit, just a bit less verbose) + the resharper test runner for IDE integration.