# Which unit test framework in VS2010 - MSTest or NUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, nunit, mstest

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Ms Test or NUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901219/ms-test-or-nunit)
>   [NUnit vs Visual Studio 2008’s Test Projects for Unit Testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92869/nunit-vs-visual-studio-2008s-test-projects-for-unit-testing)
>   [what test data approach/framework is recommended for .net unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936737/what-test-data-approach-framework-is-recommended-for-net-unit-testing) 
>   [Are there real differences between NUnit and Microsoft’s Unit Testing Framework (VS 2008)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422238/are-there-real-differences-between-nunit-and-microsofts-unit-testing-framework)

Any recommendations re whether to got MSTest or NUnit for a new project in VS2010 (C#), mainly focused at business logic layer unit tests?

Is there any major reason why I wouldn't just go with the VS2010 MSTest which is integrated there?