# what test data approach/framework is recommended for .net unit testing

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, nunit, mstest

what test data approach/framework is recommended for .net unit testing?  I'm in VS2010, C#, doing business logic layer testing.

By approaches I mean like: creating database snapshots, programmatically creating each time, etc etc. Like what approach to use to ensure at the start of each test the database is in a known state.

Answer (score 1):

Some would say that if you're using the database, then you're doing functional testing, not unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly related to database testing. But in general when we need to setup test data we can use a library called NBuilder. It can create single instance of a calss as well as a list of instances. It uses a very fluent interface and is very easy to use. I had written a [blog](http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2010/04/use-nbuilder-to-generate-test-data.html) about the same.