# How do I persist variables between tests in MSTest?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I'm using MSTest (VS2008) and I need to persist a variable between tests. However the variable gets re-initialized between every test.

According to the third point mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901219/ms-test-or-nunit/12821049#12821049),

> MSTest always instantiates a new instance of the test class for each test method being executed.

Is there a straightforward way to keep the value of a variable between tests, or somehow suppress this behaviour?

Comment: Why would you want to do that??

Comment: Can you please post your code? Where is your variable declared?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I'm running integrated tests that involve a third party REST API - creating an item, retrieving a property generated server-side, then using it for another call. It seems unreasonable to stub the whole thing considering they've got a fully functional sandbox. I'm sure there's plenty of other legitimate reasons to want to do this.

Comment: @Schaliasos The basic shape of my code is more or less the same as chue's answer, which I've just accepted.

Comment: I thought you wanted to access it from different test classes. @chue x answer is the best in your case. You can also use the `[ClassInitialize]` method if you want to make a basic initialization for all of your tests. It will run only once before all test methods. Same for `[TestCleanup]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a static member variable:

```
static int _test = 0;

[TestMethod]
public void __Test1()
{
    _test += 1;
    Assert.IsTrue(_test == 1);
}

[TestMethod]
public void __Test2()
{
    _test += 1;
    Assert.IsTrue(_test == 2);
}
```

Comment: Technically correct, but asserting _test == 2 is a very bad example. a) It fails when running alone b) there is no guaranty that the tests are run in a certain order c) you should use Assert.AreEqual when comparing values.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger - certainly valid points. The focus should definitely be on the use of the static variable as a way to achieve what the OP is asking for.