# How to run Nunit tests in visual studio with loading referenced assembly config files

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, nunit, configuration-files

I use VS 2012 and Nunit 2.6. My Test project reference one console application and one assembly. I would like the config file of the assembly to be pick up when running my tests but not the config file of the console application. 
For usual tests performed in VS, the attribute "deploymentitemattribute" seems to be a good solution. But this attribute does not exist for NUnit ([NUnit DeploymentItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378276/nunit-deploymentitem)). I am not satisfied with the solution of implementing my own class.
What do you think is the best way to share configuration files between assemblies and test projects with NUnit ?